# "Native module cannot be null" in PushNotificationManagerIOS

Tags: javascript, react-native

My code errors in NativeEventEmitter.js, and the stack shows PushNotificationManagerIOS.js as the lower file. I never used any notification features in my app, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though sometimes it might be related to a misinstalled library, replacing:

```
import * as ReactNative from "react-native";
```

with:

```
import { Text, View, /* and the other classes you want to use*/ } from "react-native";
```

fixed it for me. Remember to change `ReactNative.Foo` to just `Foo`